# find in jQuery object top level

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

What I am trying to do. I have a form which opens in new tab. I want to submit that form with some extra things:
a) Remove 'target=_blank'
b) Preserve that form intact for future

Here is sample form:

```
<div id="cloneForm">
  <form id="searchForm" method="post" target="_blank" action="#">
  </form>
</div>
```

So what I come up:
To preserve form intact I am cloning form with jQuery into variable:

```
var searchForm = $('#searchForm').clone();
var cloneForm = $('#cloneForm').clone(); // This is just for workaround
```

But selector which has worked on $('#cloneForm') `find('[target="_blank"]')` no longer works. (I wonder why?). This selector works only on "cloneForm".

So I can do two things:

- I can access target attribute in such way: `searchForm[0].target` set to something
- `cloneForm.find('[target="_blank"]').removeAttr('target')`

But neither of these two I like. I don't like adding extra div cloneForm. Neither I like accessing target via array.

Any suggestions in better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form is the top-level object in the set, and the only top-level object in the set. Just use `attr` on it:

```
cloneForm.attr("target", "new value");
// or
cloneForm.removeAttr("target");
```

If it weren't the only object in the set, you'd use `filter` to get a new set with just that object in it:

```
cloneForm.filter('[target="_blank"]').attr("target", "new value");
// or
cloneForm.filter('[target="_blank"]').removeAttr("target");
```

...but there's no need in your case, since you know there's just the one top-level element.